# Api на разных телефонах возвращает разный timeStamp

Tags: android

Здравствуйте уважаемые пользователи StackOverflow подскажите, почему API "OpenWeatherMap" возвращает разный timeStamp на разных телефонах (устройствах на базе операционной системы Android)?

[http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Kremenchuk,ua&units=metric&appid=Ключ](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Kremenchuk,ua&units=metric&appid=%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87)

И так, есть сервис предоставления прогнозов погоды: OpenWeatherMap. Для бесплатного пользования он может возвращать прогноз погоды на пять дней с периодичностью в три часа, на каждый прогноз он выставляет дату и время на какой именно час этот прогноз. И вышло так что на одном устройстве он возвращает в часах: на 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 00. На другом: 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23. В одном и том же приложении.

Кто может разъяснить в чём причина такого поведения и от чего это зависит? Ведь в запросе нет указания часового пояса или чего-то аналогичного.

Comment: Вы уверены что именно сервер отдаёт разный штамп, а не устройства отображают его по своим настройкам? Обычно по сети передают время в `UTC`. Ну и кроме адресной строки есть ещё заголовки (куки в частности) - возможно там что-то передаётся.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть дело в кодировке передаваемого **имени объекта** и он его находит в базе по другому? Это лишь предположение...

Попробуйте определить ID объекта для этих устройств. Или добавьте параметр **type** = [like | accurate], он повышает точность поиска по имени.